# Can delphi .net develope the app for windows phone?

Tags: .net, delphi

I am Delphi programmer.
I hope move some of my app on windows to windows phone.
That language I think can be easy to learn is Delphi .net.

I just wonder if Delphi.net supports the development for Windows phone.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I just wonder if Delphi.net supports the development for Windows phone.*

- Delphi.Net does not compile to the compact framework out of the box.
  There are some hacks to get it working though: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33507.
  I've tried to do the stuff in the tutorial. It's a neat hack, but a pain when you actually want to get stuff done. So I wouldn't bother with that. Besides, Delphi.Net is dead.
- If you're serious with Delphi.Net, you should look into Prism instead.
  The [FAQ on embarcadero's site](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism/faq#28) says:

> ***Can I build applications for the
>   Compact Framework using Delphi Prism?***
>
> Delphi Prism will compile against the
>   CF assemblies. However, there is no
>   design-time support as the Compact
>   Framework designers are closely
>   integrated with the C# and VB.NET
>   personalities of Visual Studio and not
>   available for use by other language
>   plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

Lazarus with native WinCE support is of course also an option. And that is full LCL use.

(though the LCL/VCL is less useful with small screens, it works nicely with e.g. WinCE controlled machines)

Comment: Full VCL on WinCE? Including all the non-WinCE bells and whistles?

Comment: Full LCL obviously (I'll correct that in the post), I meant VCL as in a LCL/VCL RAD app without a tailor made framework for CE),  Of course parts that WinCE doesn't support won't work.

Comment: +1 .. my mini goal for the coming weekend: getting a "hello world" application to run on my phone via Lazarus.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop for Windows Phone Classic (aka Windows Mobile), Delphi Prism or classic Delphi for .NET are not an option.

If you want to develop for Windows Phone 7, you may consult Embarcadero for clarification, as their partner RemObjects shows the possibility,

http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/jim/2010/11/25/p2066

Comment: If you want to develop for Windows Phone 7 / Windows Phone 8 using delphi - RemObjects 's Oxygene is one possibility . Some articles on how to develop WP8 app using RemObjects Oxygene can be found at http://mobileosgeek.com/?s=oxygene

Answer (score 0):

A bit offtopic: you can visit [Developer Solutions Conference](http://www.dsconf.com) to get the detailed answer to your exact question.